# How can I customize the AuditingEntityListener injected by Spring-Data when using Auditing?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I try to add @PreRemove to my AuditingEntityListener to audit my data when use soft delete data in Spring , but i found it dosn't work, dose any guy have any suggest, Many thanks

```
public class MyAuditingEntityListener extends AuditingEntityListener{

    @PreRemove
    public void touchForRemove(Object target) {
        this.touchForUpdate(target);
    }
}
```